# How is “any more than” used to compare two different situations?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, expressions, conjunctions

In the following quote by Billy Sunday

> Going to church doesn’t make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile.

Can anyone please explain/elaborate the usage and meaning of "any more than"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The construction *[not X] any more than [Y]* is a way of comparing a primary negative assertion to an obviously absurd positive secondary assertion. The underlying logic is:

> [X] is not any more true than [Y] … *that is, it is equally **un**true*
>   [Going to church makes you a Christian] is not any more true than [going to a garage makes you a car].

Move the denial into the primary proposition, and you have:

> [X is not true] any more than [Y]

*Is not true* reduces, in context, to *VERBs not*, so you end up with:

> [Going to church **doesn’t make** you a Christian] any more than [going to a garage makes you a car].

Comment: “is as untrue as (an obviously untrue statement),” right?

Answer (score 8):

This is merely a comparison of two things.

> Doing A doesn't mean that you're an X.  (church)
>   Doing B doesn't mean that you're a Y.   (garage)
>   Therefore, A and B are **equally ineffective** measures of your true nature.  OR
>   Therefore, your doing A doesn't tell us more about your true nature than your doing B does.

So both A and B have zero value as signs of your character and nature. They are equal.

Here's [another example of the usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question):

> The distinction between a "formal" fallacy and a "material" fallacy is not fixed or clear--**any more than** that between "formal" and "material" logic.

In this case, what these two pairs of terms mean and how each member of a pair differs from its opposite is **equally unclear and unfixed**.

Answer (score -1):

"any more than" can be a substitute for "even if" for example. Going to church does not make you a Christian even if going to a garage makes you a car. The whole idea of the sentence is that while going to a garage does not make you a car, likewise going to a church does not necessarily make you a christian.

Comment: "...even if going to a garage makes you a car" implies that going to a garage DOES make you a car. "Any more than" means exactly the opposite. Going to a garage doesn't make you a car, and going to church doesn't make you a Christian.