# Understanding the negative comparison "I didn't want to see her any more than she wanted to see me"

Tags: comparative-constructions

While I was studying I saw a sentence but I can't understand it.  Here is the sentence;

> As, I didn't want to see her any more than she wanted to see me I didn't mind when she told me so.

I don't understand the "than she wanted to see me" part.

Now we got two person they don't want to talk each other any more but here it says "than she wanted".

I thought she wanted to see him but he didn't want to see her, but in paragraph feelings are mutual.

I don't understand construction of this sentence. Did she want to see him or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is “any more than” used to compare two different situations?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/how-is-any-more-than-used-to-compare-two-different-situations)

Comment: They both had _very little_ desire to see one another. He didn't want it any more than she did.

Comment: The sentence is confusing because we would normally say just: **I didn't want to see her any more**, meaning **see her again**. But here, the expression **any more than** is used: So you can break it up to understand it: I didn't want to see her - any more than - she wanted to see me.

Comment: Is there any reduction or something because While ı was reading this ı felt like there should be "not" or something I Didnt want to see her like she ///didnt/// want to see me but when it says she wanted thats confusing my mind like she want to see him. I couldnt understand the mutual expression here

Comment: The degree to which she wanted to see him was _very little_ - that is, she _didn't_ want to. He didn't want it any more than  she did.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it simply means that neither of them wanted to see the other.

It could also be broken up as "She didn't want to see me at all, but I didn't want to see her either, so I didn't mind when she told me so."

Comment: There is also the implication that the degree of objection is equal in both directions, or that the speaker's objection is stronger. To be clearer if her objection to seeing me was 80% my objection to seeing her was at least 80% and possibly 90% or 100%.